# angular how to refresh or reload directive on external event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular 1.3

Plunker code here  http://plnkr.co/edit/J7TSfUcNID11BZBEaBBr?p=preview

In my code, I have ngRoute which defines a controller for the index page and it implements the fetch as below.

```
   .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/assets/app/html/home.partial.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.fetch = function(purchase) {
                    console.log("fetch is called, load data and show the grid");
                    $scope.grid = {};
                    $scope.grid.isActive = true;
                    //how to refresh purchases directive from here
                    //it should also pass the from and to dates
                    //based on that purchases will fetch the backend data
                }
            }
        })

}]);
```

I have a directive Purchases which I am trying to reload including fetching the data through resources.  When the date changes, I want to query the data again from backend and refresh it on the grid inside the Purchases directive.

I use ngResource plugin so fetching data from the backend is sorted out.
When loading the page, the link function runs only once.

What is the best way to pass the from and to dates to the directive (check the plunker index.html)?

When the date is changed, I dont see the directive (link function) picking it up. I tried html id, name and model, but none of them worked.

Comment: How are you passing dates into the directive? Are you using an isolate scope? Have you tried using `scope.$watch`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're fetching the data and giving it to the director to render based on it. Keeping that in mind there is one easy way to "refresh" the directive and its to use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf). if the expression inside ng-if is false then the directive is destroyed, if it's true then it is instantiated newly. If it is instantiated newly based on the new data then it will show the new data as well. That is one way to refresh the directive.

Ideally your grid should seamlessly change based on if your data changes as AngularJS has two way binding. If your code is not created in that manner then you can just refresh the directive using ng-if.

Comment: I have tried ng-if, ng-show and ng-hide but none of them work the way I want it to be or I am not getting it.  ng-if doesnt work for situations where I can change the from and to dates at will and expect the grid data to update accordingly.